# How to set landscape orientation mode for flutter app?

Tags: flutter, orientation, flutter-layout

I was looking for code which can set orientation of my flutter app landscape forcefully.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Enable forcefully**

Import package: `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';` in `main.dart` file

**1. Landscape mode:**

```
// Set landscape orientation
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
]);
```

[image]

**2. Portrait mode:**

```
// Set portrait orientation
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
   DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
   DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
]);
```

[image: Set portrait mode]

Comment: Does this work for the camera as well?  App needs to take photos of things like motorbikes and passports which are better suited to Landscape mode. Written in flutter for both iOS and Android.

Comment: @Bruno not tested in camera, try and update

Answer (score 10):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main()  {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft])
   .then((_) {
    runApp(new MyApp());
  });
}
```

Comment: is there a reason doing it this way is preferable (or not) to the accepted answer that puts a similar line of code at the start of MyApp's build()?

Comment: @MoralCode Well.. flutter's official documentation itself suggest calling setPreferredOrientations on main(), before runApp(). I think this is better, to force various android UI into landscape position as soon as possible. Also it's worth noticing then the official documentation doesn't advocate the using of then(), even though this method is asynchronous; probably because it is a pretty fast operation anyway.

Answer (score 6):

`SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` is applicable for Flutter part of the app, but it's not a full solution. Because when you launching the app - Flutter are not created yet. So you should also setup orientation in the native parts.

Here the article with detailed instructions https://medium.com/@greymag/flutter-orientation-lock-portrait-only-c98910ebd769

Comment: He's right. If you want to change the "app" orientation, you should do that from the native part. Although, use cases differ. Sometimes, you may need to force only a specific screen to be landscape or portrait.