# Flutter: how to disable device orientation changes?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to make orientation only to portrait or landscape in flutter? Thanks.

Comment: I asked how to disable orientation change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set landscape orientation mode for flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806662/how-to-set-landscape-orientation-mode-for-flutter-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use `SystemChrome` in your main method. For example:

To lock orientation to landscape, use:

```
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight, DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]
   );
```

To lock orientation to portrait, use:

```
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitRight, DeviceOrientation.portraitLeft]
   );
```