# Force landscape mode in flutter apps - in iOS & Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Our app requires photos of things like motorbikes & passports.  Both of which are much better suited to landscape photos.  How can we force landscape mode during these photo captures?

Apps are written in flutter and have both iOS and Android versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set landscape orientation mode for flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806662/how-to-set-landscape-orientation-mode-for-flutter-app) or [How to set and lock screen orientation on-demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322054/flutter-how-to-set-and-lock-screen-orientation-on-demand)

Comment: @Chance thanks mate.  I've forwarded to developers.

Answer (score 1):

For SystemChrome you have to add  package

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

for landscape mode add this code

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //for landscape mode
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  }
```

You get normal page

```
 @override
dispose(){
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, will forward his to devs.